# Wheel Colliders falling through ground

Tags: unity, collider, meshcollider

I have read through hours of forums and tried everything, But this issue still persists. I have attached a video showing the issue as well as all of my collider settings. Any help would be appreciated.

https://youtu.be/KiTAY2nXfOo

Comment: Please edit your question to document the steps needed to produce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem in the body of your question itself. External links are useful as supporting material, but your question should still be able to stand on its own even without clicking the link - making the knowledge repository here robust against link rot, regional exclusions, etc.

Comment: Please verify whether either your plane or your wheel has a Rigidbody component attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw, the weight of the tire seems disproportionate to the weight of the car. Try to lower the weight of the tires.

(While in play mode, showing the screen and selecting the entire car and showing rigidbody component may be more helpful to understand whether the tires are flying or not)